# Regex excluding all numbers

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hello I'm trying to search all the matching expressions in a file through a Regex in VB.NET 
I have the function:

```
Dim written As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(ToTreat, "\bGlobalIndexImage = \'(?![0-9])([A-Za-z])\w+\'")
For Each writ As Match In written
    For Each w As Capture In writ.Captures
        MsgBox(w.Value.ToString)
    Next
Next
```

I have this Regex now:

```
\bGlobalIndexImage = \'(?![0-9])([A-Za-z])\w+\'
```

I'm trying to match all occurrences under this form:

```
GlobalIndexImage = 'images'
GlobalIndexImage = 'Search'
```

But I also get values like this which I don't want to match:

```
GlobalIndexImage = 'Z0003_S16G2'
```

So I wanted in my Regex to simply exclude a match if it contains numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\w` shorthand character class matches letters *and* digits *and* `_`. If you need only letters, just use `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
"\bGlobalIndexImage = '([A-Za-z]+)'"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CbGlobalIndexImage%20%3D%20%27%28%5BA-Za-z%5D%2B%29%27&i=GlobalIndexImage%20%3D%20%27images%27%0D%0AGlobalIndexImage%20%3D%20%27Search%27).

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `GlobalIndexImage = '` -  a string of literal chars
- `([A-Za-z]+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more (due to `+` quantifier) ASCII letters
- `'` -  a single quote.

[image]

If you need to match any Unicode letters, replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\p{L}`.

VB.NET:

```
Dim text = "GlobalIndexImage = 'images' GlobalIndexImage = 'Search'"
Dim pattern As String = "\bGlobalIndexImage = '([A-Za-z]+)'"
Dim matches As List(Of String) = Regex.Matches(text, pattern) _
                                    .Cast(Of Match)() _
                                    .Select(Function(m) m.Groups(1).Value) _
                                    .ToList()
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbLf, matches))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks works perfect. By the same occasion do you know if there's a quick  way with vb.net to get the $1 shown in your picture?

Comment: Do you prefer a Linq approach?

Comment: I don't mind either I could simply split the string on the **'** But i though maybe there's already a method to do it .

Comment: There is no specific methods for extracting just a specific group value. Use `Regex.Matches`, iteratre through the matches and collect the `.Group(1).Value`.

Answer (score 1):

To catch everything that's not a number use `\D`

So your regex will be something like

```
\bGlobalIndexImage = \'\d+\'
```

But this will also include words with white spaces. To get only letters use `[a-zA-Z]`

```
\bGlobalIndexImage = \'[a-zA-Z]+\'
```